# What kind of tools are available to package source code

Tags: svn, maven-2, maven

I would like to create a package (devoid of SVN entries, Eclipse settings) from a project stored in SVN and managed using maven. I should be able to create a package which I can re-use as a snapshot at a latter point in time. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your have setup your project with a SCM, maven will ignore the .svn directories and as long as your eclipse properties files aren't within your "src" folders, you won't get those either.  Your -SNAPSHOT versions can be deployed and reused later.

If you just want to have the SVN repository "SNAPSHOT" saved for later, I would suggest just using a SVN "TAG" to save that point in time within the repository.  That can be done using the [Maven SCM Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/index.html)

At that point you can always checkout the tagged version and continue from that exact revision.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this. One of the simplest ways is to use scripts (shell/batch/powershell) and do an svn export. This will get a specified revision of the source code without the SVN entries, unlike svn checkout. Essentially, you will be executing the following command in your script:

```
svn export [-r REV] URL[@PEGREV] [PATH]
```

You can add the commands to remove the eclipse setting in your script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [maven source plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/index.html) to do this.